# How to Register an Attached Property of Textbox Text So Datagrid Can Update on Change

Tags: wpf, xaml, behavior

I have a textbox and a datagrid like so:

```
<Page
    TextElement.FontSize="14" FontFamily="Segoe UI"
    Title="Delivery View">
    <Page.Resources>
        <xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource x:Key="firstNameDataSource" 
                                           Source="{Binding Path=Accessor.Views[FirstNameView].SourceCollection}"
                                           AutoFilterMode="And"
                                           DistinctValuesConstraint="Filtered">
            <xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource.ItemProperties>
                <xcdg:DataGridItemProperty Name="FirstName" CalculateDistinctValues="False"/>
            </xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource.ItemProperties>            
        </xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource>
    </Page.Resources>
    <ScrollViewer Name="pendingScroll" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <DockPanel Name="pnlMainPanel" LastChildFill="True" Style="{StaticResource panelBackground}">
            <Grid Margin="15">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" FontSize="18" Text="Pending Guests" Margin="0,1,3,1" Foreground="SteelBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <TextBox Name="txtFirstNameFilter" Grid.Row="1" >                    
                </TextBox>
                    <xcdg:DataGridControl x:Name="gridPendingGuests" Margin="5,0,5,1"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                  MinHeight="100"
                                  MinWidth="200"
                                CellEditorDisplayConditions="None"
                                EditTriggers="None"
                                ItemScrollingBehavior="Immediate"
                                AutoCreateColumns="False"
                                SelectionMode="Single"
                                NavigationBehavior="RowOnly"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource firstNameDataSource}}">
                        <xcdg:DataGridControl.View>
                            <xcdg:TableView ShowRowSelectorPane="False"/>
                        </xcdg:DataGridControl.View>
                        <xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
                            <xcdg:Column x:Name="FirstName" FieldName="FirstName" Title="First Name" Width="150" />
                        </xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
                        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <utils:UpdateDataGridOnTextboxChange/>
                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    </xcdg:DataGridControl>
            </Grid>
        </DockPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Page>
```

In the datagrid, you have a collection of first names. This works perfectly. The display is good. As you can see, I added an Interactions.Behavior class which currently handles a filter with a hard coded value when the user clicks on the datagrid with their mouse. The filtering works fine. If there is a first name of "John", that record is removed from view, leaving all other records in place.

Here is that code:

```
using System.Windows.Interactivity;
using System.Windows;
using Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid;
using System;

namespace Some.Namespace.Behaviors
{
    public class UpdateDataGridOnTextboxChange : Behavior<DataGridControl>
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            AssociatedObject.MouseUp += AssociatedObjectOnMouseUp;
            base.OnAttached();
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            AssociatedObject.MouseUp -= AssociatedObjectOnMouseUp;
            base.OnDetaching();
        }

        private void AssociatedObjectOnMouseUp(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
        {
            var items = AssociatedObject.Items;
            items.Filter = CollectionFilter;
        }

        private bool CollectionFilter(object item)
        {
            System.Data.DataRow dr = item as System.Data.DataRow;

            //set the ItemArray as Guest
            Guest guest = SetGuest(dr);

            if (guest.FirstName.Equals("John"))
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;            
        }

        private Guest SetGuest(System.Data.DataRow dr)
        {
            Guest guest = new Guest();
            guest.FirstName = dr.ItemArray[0].ToString();
            return guest;
        } 

        public class Guest
        {
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
        }

    }
}
```

This works as expected. Again, when the user clicks on the datagrid, the filter filters out the users with the First Name of "John".

What I WANT to have happen is for the user to be able to type a first name in the txtFirstNameFilter Textbox and the datagrid to then filter the records that contain the text in the first name, keeping them visible and the others without that first name to not be visible.

The way I can do it is with an attached property of the Textbox TextChanged property? That's a question, because I don't know how to do an attached property and then how to make sure that when that attached property actually changes, call the AssociatedObjectOnMouseUp method to run the filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`System.Windows.Interactivity.Behavior<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff726531%28v=expression.40%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) inherits from DependencyObject. So give it a dependency property and bind that.

```
public class UpdateDataGridOnTextboxChange : Behavior<DataGrid>
{
    #region FilterValue Property
    public String FilterValue
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(FilterValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FilterValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FilterValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(FilterValue), typeof(String), typeof(UpdateDataGridOnTextboxChange),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FilterValue_PropertyChanged));

    protected static void FilterValue_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (d as UpdateDataGridOnTextboxChange).OnFilterValueChanged(e.OldValue);
    }

    private void OnFilterValueChanged(object oldValue)
    {
        //  Do whatever you do to update the filter
        //  I did a trace just for testing. 

        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine($"Filter value changed from '{oldValue}' to '{FilterValue}'");
    }
    #endregion FilterValue Property

    /*****************************************

         All your code here

     *****************************************/
}
```

XAML:

```
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <utils:UpdateDataGridOnTextboxChange
                    FilterValue="{Binding Text, ElementName=txtFirstNameFilter}"
                    />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

You should rename it, though. It's got nothing to do with text boxes. You could bind `FilterValue` to a viewmodel property, or the selected value in a ComboBox, or whatever.

---

### Update

OP's having trouble with the binding only updating `FilterValue` when the text box loses focus. This isn't what I'm seeing, but I don't know what's different between the two.

There isn't any UpdateTargetTrigger property of `Binding`, but you can swap the source and the target when both are dependency properties of dependency objects. This works for me:

```
<TextBox 
    x:Name="txtFirstNameFilter"
    Text="{Binding FilterValue, ElementName=DataGridFilterThing, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    />

<!-- snip snip snip -->

<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <local:UpdateDataGridOnTextboxChange
        x:Name="DataGridFilterThing"
        />
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Comment: Is the ElementName the name of the TextBox in the XAML? So, in this case it would be FilterValue="{Binding Text, ElementName=txtFirstNameFilter}"?

Comment: @crackedcornjimmy Yes, it would be that in your case. Updated.

Comment: I'm almost there. I can type a value into the txtFirstNameFilter text box and yet nothing happens. But, when I navigate away from the view (whether it's shutting down the application or simply moving somewhere else in the application), the code fires and I can filter the datagrid. Is there someway I can trigger the Filtering code to run on KeyUp in the textbox?

Comment: For me, the binding was updating `FilterValue` on every keystroke in the TextBox. Did you put a breakpoint in `FilterValue_PropertyChanged`? Maybe bind both FilterValue and TextBox.Text to a viewmodel property and add `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to the binding on `TextBox.Text`?

Comment: What if I told you I don't have a viewmodel?

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it is correct. The other issue is my own quirky issue. But the guts work correctly